# How to see image data using opencv in visual studio?

Tags: image, visual-studio-2010, debugging, opencv

I wrote an OPENCV project in VS2010 and the results were not the ones as I expected so I ran the debugger to see where is the problem. When I wanted to see the data inside the image loaded I didn't know how to do it so if I want to see the data inside my images what should I do?
It is pretty simple in matlab for seeing different channel of an image i.e.

```
a=imread('test.jpg');
p1 = a(:,:,1)
p2 = b(:,:,2)

.
.
```

In opencv I wrote the same thing but I don't know how to see all the element at once just like Matlab.

```
a= imread("test.jpg")
split(a,planes);
    vector<Mat> T1;
    T1 = planes[0];
```

// How can I see the data inside T1 when debugging the code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080283/debugging-unmanaged-c-images-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you are looking for - it's a great Visual Studio add-on

https://bitbucket.org/sergiu/opencv-visualizers

Just download the installer, make sure VS is closed, run it, re-open VS and voila! Now, when you point to an OpenCV data structure, all kinds of nice info is showed.

Limitations: I saw some problems with multichannel images (it only shows the first channel) and it also has trouble displaying large matrices. If you want to see raw data in a big matrix, you can use the old good VS trick with debug variables: Stop at a breakpoint, go to Watch tab, and write there

```
((float*)myMat.data) ,10
```

Where float is the matrix type, myMat is your matrix, and 10  is the number of values you want to print. It will display the first 10 values at the memory location of myMat.data. If you do not correctly choose the data type, you'll see garbage. In my example, myMat is of type cv::Mat.

And never forget the power of visualizers:

```
imshow("Image", myMat);
```

If your data fits into an image. You can use the contrib module's colormap to enhance your visualizers.

Comment: Just a question - [Image Watch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24196113/492336) also paints the actual image - see the orange and other fruits in the screenshot in the link. Does opencv-visualizers do the same? Because I'm looking for that functionality, and at first I thought that opencv-visualizers does exactly that, but now I installed it, and I suspect it doesn't, it just shows the data in a slightly better way.

Answer (score 6):

I can't actually believe that nobody suggested [Image Watch](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e682d542-7ef3-402c-b857-bbfba714f78d) yet. It's the most amazing add-in ever. It shows you a view with all your Mat variables (images (gray and color), matrices) while debugging, there's useful stuff like zooming or contrast-stretching and you can even apply more complex functions directly in the plugin in real-time. It makes debugging of any kind of image operations a breeze and it's immensely helpful if you do calculations and linear algebra stuff with your cv::Mat matrices.

[image]

Comment: It requires VS2012, though, so it doesn't work with VS2010 (which is what OP is using, and incidentally, me).

Comment: Well if you don't have a *very* good reason for using VS2010, you should upgrade anyway, if not for plugins then for standard conformance. And there's now a free community edition of VS2013.

Comment: Actually, I found that NativeViewer works for VS2010 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156160/visualize-opencv-images-in-vs2010-debugger

Comment: VS2019 version: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCPPTeam.ImageWatch2019

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a plug-in or extension to Visual Studio, you can access the elements one by one in the debugging watch tab by typing this:

T1.data[T1.step.buf[0]*i + T1.step.buf[1]*j];

where i is the row you want to look at and j is the column.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a [NativeViewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nativeviewer/) extension. It actually displays the content of an image in a preview window, not only the properly formatted info.

Answer (score 0):

after downloading imagewatch use the command in watch window
(imagesLoc._Myfirst)[0]

index of image in the vector

Answer (score 0):

You can use the immediate window and the extenshion method like this one

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Displays image
    /// </summary>
    public static void Display (this Mat m, Rect rect = default, string windowName = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(windowName))
        {
            windowName = m.ToString();
        }
        var img = rect == default ? m : m.Crop(rect);

        double coef = Math.Min(1600d / img.Width, 800d / img.Height);

        Cv2.ImShow(windowName, img.Resize(new Size(coef * img.Width, (coef * img.Height) > 1 ? coef * img.Height : 1)));
        Cv2.WaitKey();
    }
```

Then you stop at a breakpoint and call yourImage.Display() in the immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CLion you can utilize the OpenCV Image Viewer plugin, which displays matrices while debugging just on click.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14371-opencv-image-viewer

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm an author of this plugin