# Visualize OpenCV images in VS2010 debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

For VS2012, the excellent Image Watch extension is available, which allows you to view the actual picture of a cv::Mat during debugging.

But, unfortunately, it requires VS2012. Is there a way to visualize a cv::Mat in VS2010?

I know about https://bitbucket.org/sergiu/opencv-visualizers, but they just format the data better, they don't display it as a picture (or I couldn't find the option/tab?), like Image Watch does.

So is it impossible to do that in VS2010?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an extension that does just this. It's called NativeViewer. Just follow [their quick start guide](http://sourceforge.net/p/nativeviewer/wiki/QuickStartGuide_VS2010/).

It allows you to view cv::Mat variables:

[image]

**Note:** You need to press Ctrl **BEFORE** hovering above the cv::Mat variable, not after you have hovered. This burned me, and I spent 1 hour wondering why it wasn't working, I really wish they had put a warning with bold and uppercase letters about that.